# Azure Pipeline mounting fails

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using Azure Pipeline to automated build my Yocto Project in a docker container.
Here is snapshot of the code syntax (Azure Pipeline .yml file)

```
trigger:
- main

resources:
  containers:
  - container: abc-build
    image: my-docker-registry-address
    options:
    volumes: /mnt:/mnt
```

But it has error while executing, Please refer to below :
[image]

I fail to do mounting between my build server and docker container, both are Linux environment.
Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: "/mnt:/mnt:rw" <-- fails to execute too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this and it works

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: abc-build
    image: my-docker-registry-address
    options:
    volumes:
    - /mnt:/mnt
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [mark it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), In this case, others could directly find the useful solution and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)